# SQLAlchemy: Set audit columns prior to insert or update

Tags: sqlalchemy, auditing

Each of my mapped class contains `created_by` and `updated_by` audit properties that I would like to set automatically upon INSERT and UPDATE of respective objects.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    ...

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    street = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    ...
    created_by = Column(BigInteger)  # references user.id
    updated_by = Column(BigInteger)  # references user.id
    ...
```

Is there a way to handle this centrally in SQLAlchemy? I looked at the events but it appears it needs to be setup for every single mapped class individually (note the `SomeClass` in the decorator).

```
@event.listens_for(SomeClass, 'before_insert')
def on_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    target.created_by = context["current_user"] # I want to be able to do this not just for 'SomeClass' but for all mapped classes
```

```
@event.listens_for(SomeClass, 'before_update')
def on_update(mapper, connection, target):
    target.updated_by = context["current_user"] # I want to be able to do this not just for 'SomeClass' but for all mapped classes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution here is to use the default parameters in the `Column` class provided by `sqlalchemy`. You can actually pass a callable to both `default` (to execute when first created) and `onupdate` to execute whenever updated.

```py
def get_current_user():
    return context["user"].id


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    ...
    created_by = Column(default = get_current_user)
    updated_by = Column(default = get_current_user, onupdate=get_current_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out, though somewhat concerned about using a dunder method `__subclasses__()` on `declarative_base`. If there is a better alternative do suggest.

```
def on_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    target.created_by = context["user"].id
    target.updated_at = datetime.utcnow()


def on_update(mapper, connection, target):
    target.updated_by = context["user"].id
    target.updated_at = datetime.utcnow()


Base.metadata.create_all()

mapped_classes = Base.__subclasses__()
for mapped_class in mapped_classes:
    event.listen(mapped_class, 'before_insert', on_insert)
    event.listen(mapped_class, 'before_update', on_update)
```

The context being referred to here is actually [starlette-context](https://starlette-context.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fastapi.html)